# How to generate different input file with javascript with a different id?

Tags: javascript, file-io

I use this function to generate inputs type file :
function add() {
    $('

').insertAfter("#rajout");
  }
the problem is that all input type file have the same id and everything how can I change the id each time?
Thank you

Comment: You should read about it here : https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ and to get different names, use something like an counter Rijad mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Store a counter above the function and name the inputs with it in name, maybe something like this

```
var counter = 0;
function add() { 
  var counter = 0;
  var newInput = document.createElement("input");
  var i = (counter == 0) ? '' : counter;
  var referenceInput = document.querySelector('#rajout' + i);
  counter++;
  newInput.id = 'rajout' + counter;
  referenceInput.after(newInput);
}
```

Updated the answer with a bit more complete solution (sorry for the last one)

Comment: Try switch the augment and the selector. Your answer is correct if it would be .after()  On $('contentToInsert').insertAfter(noteWhereToInsert)